# On the Poisson binomial distribution bounded by the binomial distribution at its center

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, binomial-distribution, upper-lower-bounds

The statement I am trying to prove is the following:

> Given a Poisson binomial $S$ whose parameters $p=(p_1, \dots, p_n)$ are bounded by 0.5, and where $n$ is even. Proof that,
> $$ P(S=n/2) \leq P(B=n/2),$$ where $B$ is the binomial distribution with
> parameters n and 0.5.

I think it should be true, but I could not prove it...

The pmf found on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_binomial_distribution) is hard to work with. I found that $p_1 = p_2 = \dots = p_n = 0.5$ is a saddle point of $P(S=n/2)$, but I don't know if there are other stationary points inside $[0, 0.5]^n$.

Alternatively, using [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2280251/how-to-show-a-possion-binomial-random-variable-dominates-another-possion-binomia), it is possible to bound the cmf of $S$ using the cmf of $B$, i.e.,
$$P(S\geq k) \leq P(B\geq k)$$
for all $k\in \{1,\dots,n\}$. But I'm not able to transfer it to the pmf.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one way that seems to work:

Let $n=2p$. Using the pmf of the Poisson-Binomial distribution we have
$$\mathbb{P}(S=p)=\sum_{T\subset\{1,\cdots,n\}, |T|=p}\prod_{i\in T}p_i\prod_{i\in T^c}(1-p_i).$$
This expression is linear in each $p_i$. Therefore, if all values $p_i$ are fixed except for some $p_j$ then $\mathbb{P}(S=p)$ is either increasing or deacreasing wrt $p_j$. This shows that $\mathbb{P}(S=p)$ reaches its maximum value at some point $(p_1,\cdots, p_n)$ such that $p_i=0$ or $1/2$ for all $i$. Let $E$ be the set of $i$ such that $p_i=0$. We consider that if $i\notin E$ then $p_i=1/2$. In this case, $\mathbb{P}(S=p)$ can be rewritten the following way:
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{P}(S=p)&=\sum_{T\subset\{1,\cdots,n\}, |T|=p, T\cap E=\emptyset}\prod_{i\in T}p_i\prod_{i\in T^c}(1-p_i) + \sum_{T\subset\{1,\cdots,n\}, |T|=p, T\cap E\neq\emptyset}\prod_{i\in T}p_i\prod_{i\in T^c}(1-p_i).\\
&= \sum_{T\subset\{1,\cdots,n\}\backslash E, |T|=p}\frac{1}{2^{n-|E|}} + 0\\
&= \binom{n-|E|}{p}\frac{1}{2^{n-|E|}}.
\end{align*}
If $|E|\geq 1$ then using Pascal's triangle recursion formula we get
$$\binom{n-|E|}{p} + \binom{n-|E|}{p-1} = \binom{n-(|E|-1)}{p}.$$
Now, we know that $\binom{n}{k}$ is increasing wrt $k$ when $k\leq n/2$ and decreasing when $k\geq n/2$. In our case, since $p=n/2$ then $p\geq p-1 \geq \frac{n-|E|}{2}$ hence $\binom{n-|E|}{p-1}\geq \binom{n-|E|}{p}$ and thus $\binom{n-(|E|-1)}{p}\geq 2 \binom{n-|E|}{p}$ and finally
$$\binom{n-(|E|-1)}{p} \frac{1}{2^{n-(|E|-1)}} \geq \binom{n-|E|}{p}\frac{1}{2^{n-|E|}}.$$
$\mathbb{P}(S=p)$ is thus maximized when $|E|=0$ and thus
$$\mathbb{P}(S=p)\leq \binom{n}{p}\frac{1}{2^n} = \mathbb{P}(B=p).$$