# An inequality for $E \prod (1+ a_i X_i)$ conditioned on $\sum X_i =0$

Tags: probability, inequality, polynomials

Let $a_i$ be $n$ real numbers in $[0,1]$, with $n$ even. Let $X_i$ be iid Rademacher random variables: $P(X_i=1)=P(X_i=-1)=\frac12$.

Is this inequality true?

$$E\left[ \prod_{i=1}^n (1+ a_i X_i) \mid \sum_{i=1}^n X_i =0 \right]=
\frac{1}{\binom{n}{n/2}} \sum_{x_i\in \{1,-1\} \atop \sum x_i=0}  \prod_{i=1}^n (1+ a_i x_i)
 \le 1$$

It's easy to assert it for $n=2$, as $\frac12 \left[ (1+a_1)(1-a_2) + (1-a_1)(1+a_2) \right]=1 - a_1 a_2 \le 1$

This was motivated by [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4699684/on-the-poisson-binomial-distribution-bounded-by-the-binomial-distribution-at-its).